# FlowDefinition isn’t supported

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, summer19

I have an up to date SFDX and plugins. I continue to get the flow definition error when pushing with Illuminated Cloud to my scratch org. I am not sure what the next steps should be as I have followed the release notes for summer '19. Any suggestions other than uninstalling and reinstalling?

```
Olivias-MBP:~ oliviaporter$ sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 2.2.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.5 (core)
analytics 1.1.2 (core)
generator 1.1.0 (core)
salesforcedx 46.6.0
├─ force-language-services 46.11.0
└─ salesforce-alm 46.10.0

sfdx-cli 7.15.3 (core)
```

> Salesforce DX WARNING: FlowDefinition isn’t supported in the
>   Salesforce CLI for API version 44.0 and later. Make sure that the
>   flowDefinitions directory is empty and that you’ve upgraded the flow
>   files per the instructions in the Metadata API Developer Guide:
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm#md_flow_upgrade.

I have tried to manually empty out the flow definition folder but still received the error.

Update:
In the package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>FlowDefinition</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Do you have `FlowDefinition` in your `package.xml`?

Comment: I do. I updated the post with how it is written in the package.xml

Comment: version 44 changed the flowdefinitions by changing how flow versions are referenced. Have you updated your project? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fullname_upgrade_cli.htm

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround - I added flow definitions to the .forceIgnore file and was able to move forward with development.

It's not ideal so if anyone else has a different suggestion I am open!

Comment: Did you find a solution vs. just adding flow definitions to forceignore file?

Answer (score 1):

Try fully deleting the flowDefinitions folder from your local and pushing again. Pushing to a scratch org would not rely on the Metadata API or package.xml. I would expect illuminated cloud to use sfdx force:source:push, which simply looks at your local for working out what metadata to push.

Otherwise, in your sfdx project directory, you can try removing the flowDefinition entries. Navigate to '.sfdx/orgs//sourcePathInfos.json' and remove the entries for any flowDefinitions. This will stop sfdx from trying to sync and track that metadata type. This step is quite dodgy, so be careful if you have a lot of work stored in your scratch.

If you have removed the flowDefinitions folder already, creating a new scratch (hopefully this is easy to do, depending on project complexity) and pushing the project to it should give you a clean scratch with no definitions and no tracking info for those flowDefinitions, allowing you to continue development.